# How to programmatically send the Enter key in C

Tags: c

This is a C console/terminal program.

I would like to let the user wait for the program to do some background work until either the background work finishes or the user clicks on the `<Enter>` key. I do that with a statement:

```
getchar();
```

and I have another thread doing the background work.
When the thread is about to finish, I would like the thread to send programmatically the `<Enter>` key so that the control continues after the `getchar()` statement.

How is this possible?

Comment: In plain standard C? That's not possible. You need to use OS-specific functionality to insert text into "standard input" of the process.

Comment: @KfirVentura Yes, it writes a character to ***`stdout`***, while the OP wants to read from `stdin`. Output to `stdout` doesn't end up in `stdin`.

Comment: It seems like using a signal would also be a solution here.

Comment: Maybe [ungetc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3p.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getchar()` function will block until a character arrives. Though not standard C, you can use a [`select`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) call in a loop to wait until a given file handle is readable, then read it. That would go something like the following demo code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

int main(void) {
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int retval;

    puts("Waiting for a character ...");
    for (;;) {
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(0, &rfds);

        tv.tv_sec = 1;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;

        if (select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0) break;

        puts("Delay over, doing some stuff, then waiting ...");
    }

    int ch = getchar();
    printf("Character available, it was '%c'.\n", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

In your particular case, I wouldn't have an infinite loop `for(;;)`. Rather, I'd do something like:

```c
int stillRunning = 1;
while (stillRunning) {
   ...
}
```

and then have the background task set `stillRunning` to zero to cause the loop to exit regardless of a keypress.